# android startActivity .. unusual behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I need a way to start (more likely bring to front) a activity "MyActivity"...for which i only know the xml manifest (meaning i know: pachage name, class name, intent fiters - MAIN only & no particular broadcast)

So how do i start that activity??

What i use now:

```
public boolean startActivity2(String componentName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(componentName));
    if (m_ContainerActivity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
        m_ContainerActivity.startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And i call it like:

```
startActivity2("com.app.pachage/.subpack.MyActivity");
```

And this starts activity but i my process - so +10 to weird behaviour (i also have MyActivity in old process).. what i want is to bring back old one..from the back stack.

**Note**: MyActivity has no particular intents in intents filter & no broascast!

So ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it.  it may help

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

or you can try like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(getapplicationContext(), com.app.pachage.subpack.MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You are my saviour! Meaning the enumerated flags helped me...but still: to start a activity (but not in current process), broadCastReceivers are the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.app.pachage", "com.app.pachage.subpack.MyActivity");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I receive a big error: 04-23 14:41:49.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25806): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.pachage/subpachage.MyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: ... so explicit: meaning internal (this would work if activity belong to my app..and were declared in my xml)

Comment: yes, have you declared `com.app.pachage.subpack.MyActivity` in the app's manifest?

Comment: well activity is from another aplication..that aplication obviously had it in Manifest.

Comment: as I see it: to not start activity in current process i need broadCastreceiver on other app (now first app got modified, has broadCastReceiver and all is well... because broadCast starts activity on own context ...so own process) and I from second app just send broadCast.. explicit/implicit intents still need context so respectiv activity will show in my process..

Comment: this is not read from Android developer..its my opinion reached after 10-20 tests.. So yeah BroadCast solved it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting some Intent flags such as

```
I.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
```

Comment: Nop...same situation as in my example: old activity remains untouched in background ..new one is brought to front but is in my process